# Почему не меняется контент Label(WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс Querys с таким кодом -

```
MainWindow mainWindow;       
public static DataTable readEmployers()
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow()
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [employment]", ConnectionAdres);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Call Reciept");
        da.Fill(dt);   
        mainWindow.successfulConnectuon();
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        mainWindow.errorConnection(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

И такие методы в MainWindow -

```
public void successfulConnectuon()
    {
        Status.Content = "Запрос выполнен успешно";
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
public void errorConnection(Exception ex)
    {
        Status.Content = "Ошибка выполнения запроса";
    }
```

Сам Querys вызывается из другой страницы который в свою очередь вызывается из MainWindow. Проблема в том, что ошибок нет, MessageBox выводится но Label не меняется.

Comment: Кхм, так лучше не писать... Этот винегрет из работы с БД и с UI -- адский кошмар для любого более-менее вменяемого разработчика. Для WPF используйте MVVM, или на худой конец создайте хотя бы отдельный класс `Repository`, в котором проводите всю работу с БД (извлечение данных, обновление, добавление данных), а в кодбихайнде обрабатывайте события кнопок и осуществ. взаимодействие с контролами.

Comment: @Bulson мне нужно как то вывести в главное окно - успешно ли прошёл запрос или нет. А этот код пишется далеко не для вменяемого разработчика)

Comment: У вас должен быть метод, отдельный метод, который обращается к БД и извлекает данные, которые он возвращает в виде либо коллекции элементов (объектов соотв. таблице в БД),  либо в виде экземпляра объекта, либо возвращает `null`. Допустим, по нажатию на кнопку в окне, вы вызываете это метод, получаете данные, проверяете на `null` и если не нул показываете их пользователю, или сообщаете ему, что что-то пошло не так.

Comment: @Bulson то есть лучше не try/catch а if/else?

Comment: Нееет... Причем здесь `try/catch` ? Создайте отдельный метод, в котором идет работа с БД, и запускайте его на выполнение по клику на кнопке в окне.

Comment: Так у меня именно так. Есть страница с меню, есть страница с результатом запроса. По нажатии на кнопку вызывается метод readEmployers() и возвращает значение в страницу с результатом.

Comment: А это `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow()` что? В классе работающем с БД не должно быть работы элементами интерфейса.

Comment: Это чтобы вернуть текст ошибки или удачи при выполнении запроса.

Comment: На кону мочало, начинай сначала... Прочитайте мой первый комментарий, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй так

```
var win = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
win.successfulConnectuon();

static public MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
mainWindow.successfulConnectuon();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло. А можно его написать мне метода? Выше, под классом? Что-то типа         private static var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
?

Comment: да можно только не var это локальная переменая

Comment: напиши так static Window mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefa‌​ult();

Comment: 'Window' does not contain a defintion for 'successfultConnection' and no extension method 'successfulConnection' accepting a first argument of type 'Window' cloud be found.

Comment: я обновли ответ.как бы так должно быть

Comment: Странно. У меня не работает. Та же ошибка.

Comment: я снова ответ обновил. Попробуте.У меня все ок рабит.

Comment: Да. Теперь ошибки нет. Но при вызове метода - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
указывает на mainWindow.errorConnection(ex);

Comment: @xomem вы совершенно неверно используете `WPF`. Научитесь делать `Binding` и не надо будет делать такие дурацкие манипуляции...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Всё равно придется обращаться к главному окуну, т.к. Label на нём.

Comment: @xomem Вы не понимаете основную суть привязок, `MVVM` и других аспектов. Ваш код не как не должен быть связан напрямую с дизайном. Вы создаете коллекцию (скажем List<string> Logs), она у вас отдельно, в неком классе находится. В коде, вы работаете только с этой коллекцией, код не знает что в главном окне у вас есть скажем ListBox c именем "вася", он знает только то, что у него есть коллекция и только с ней работает. А вот дизайн привязывается при помощи биндинка к этой самой коллекции, скажем `{binding Logs}`. Почитайте про привязки и `MVVM`. То, что вы сейчас делаете - это изврат!.